# Complex numbers and their modulus

Tags: complex-numbers

Can we cancel the modulus on complex numbers?

For example:
If we have $$|x + iy| = |n + im|$$ can we simply ignore the modulus on both sides? Or is that a false assumption?

Comment: Of course **not**. You cannot even do this for real numbers: $x=-1,y=0,n=1,m=0$

Comment: If $r$ is a positive real, then the complex numbers $x+iy$ with modulus $r$ are all $x+iy$ such that $x^2+y^2=r^2$, so there is an entire circle of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not. $|-1|=|1|$, and $1\neq -1$

Comment: Then the only option in solving questions with modulus on both sides is to expand them?

Comment: @Gummybears: If you follow that option, and if you use your knowledge of Euclidean geometry and equations of circles, you will discover that it is an excellent option and that you can describe the solution set in totality.

Comment: Why did this vote deserve a downvote? Is there anything wrong with it? Can the downvoter please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Consider pairs of diametrically opposite points on the unit circle, for example.

Comment: Or any pair of points on the unit circle, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

No, because two complex numbers can be different in coordinates, but have the same modulus.

Example: $z=1+i, w=1-i$.

Answer (score 0):

There are an uncountably infinite number of complex numbers equal to a given valid modulus (for different values of the argument), so no.